# Sensational Riddle!

Tags: riddle, poetry

> Silent guide of our perception,
> Shrouded in mystery and deception.
> Easily brings forth a smile, or a tear so nice,
> Power that can stir even the coldest of ice.

> Silent whispers, carried on the wind,
> So strong, can awaken memories within.
> Nibbling on a fresh mango,
> Juices dripping, a tropical glow.

> Enchanting melodies, echoing in the air,
> Elevating the soul, relieving every care.
> Softly brushing against the skin,
> A feeling so tender, a connection to win.

*What are we?*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are:

> the five human **senses**: sight, smell, taste, hearing and touch.

*Silent guide of our perception,*
*Shrouded in mystery and deception.*

> The five senses enable us to perceive the world around us, and we can often take them for granted, so silently do they go about this task...

*Easily brings forth a smile, or a tear so nice,*
*Power that can stir even the coldest of ice.*

> This couplet refers to **sight** (and the *eye*). The sight of something (or someone) can stir emotion in us, and bring forth a smile or a tear - both actions which also involve the eyes.

*Silent whispers, carried on the wind,*
*So strong, can awaken memories within.*

> These 'silent whispers' in the air refer to the aromas that we can perceive via our sense of **smell** (and our *noses*). Familiar smells can be a memory aid, transporting us back in our minds to places we've been or people we remember...

*Nibbling on a fresh mango,*
*Juices dripping, a tropical glow.*

> Our sense of **taste** (via the *tongue*) enables us to savour delicious foods (like mango).

*Enchanting melodies, echoing in the air,*
*Elevating the soul, relieving every care.*

> With our sense of **hearing** (via the *ears*) we can listen to music and melodies, which can lift  our mood (or even quite the opposite).

*Softly brushing against the skin,*
*A feeling so tender, a connection to win.*

> Our sense of **touch** (via the *skin*) enables us to experience the textures of the world around us, and make connections with other people.

The title, of course, refers to...

> ...these **senses**! (*'Sense'-ational*...)

***OP Edit:***

> Taking first letters from each couplet we get
>
>
>     **S**ilent guide of our perception,
>     Shrouded in mystery and deception.
>
>     **E**asily brings forth a smile, or a tear so nice,
>     Power that can stir even the coldest of ice.
>
>     **S**ilent whispers, carried on the wind,
>     So strong, can awaken memories within.
>
>     **N**ibbling on a fresh mango,
>     Juices dripping, a tropical glow.
>
>     **E**nchanting melodies, echoing in the air,
>     Elevating the soul, relieving every care.
>
>     **S**oftly brushing against the skin,
>     A feeling so tender, a connection to win.
>
>     *S,E,S,N,E,S* reversing this we again get **SENSES**

Comment: Well done!! :) r13(Purpx gur svefg yrggref bs rnpu pbhcyrg sebz obggbz gb gbc ;) )

Comment: @Techidiot Aha, a sneaky hide :) Hadn't spotted that at all...

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> EMOTIONS?

*Silent guide of our perception,

Shrouded in mystery and deception.*

> Sometimes our perceptions are clouded by our emotions, and they can be mysterious or deceive us into irrational actions.

*Easily brings forth a smile, or a tear so nice,

Power that can stir even the coldest of ice.*

> Emotions can cause smiles or tears, and everyone has emotions even if they seem to be made of ice.

*Silent whispers, carried on the wind,

So strong, can awaken memories within*

> Emotions can come to us suddenly, and are often associated with memories.

*Nibbling on a fresh mango,

Juices dripping, a tropical glow.*

> I don't know if this choice of imagery means anything specific, but it's certainly a scene that could evoke emotions.

*Enchanting melodies, echoing in the air,

Elevating the soul, relieving every care.*

> Music can inspire emotions, which elevate the soul and bring us peace and calmness.

*Softly brushing against the skin,

A feeling so tender, a connection to win.*

> Physical contact can also bring emotions.

Comment: Good one but not correct. :) +1 for the attempt

Answer (score 2):

I thought you were:

> Different forms of water

Silent guide of our perception,

> There are compasses based on water

Shrouded in mystery and deception.

> Fog is associated with mystery,
>
>  and mirages aren't made of water but look as if they were

Easily brings forth a smile, or a tear so nice,

> Some people want rain and others get melancholic instead

Power that can stir even the coldest of ice.

> When glaciers break, water carries the icebergs

Silent whispers, carried on the wind,

> Clouds are carried on the wind

So strong, can awaken memories within.

> Water can awaken the genetic memories within seeds

Nibbling on a fresh mango,
Juices dripping, a tropical glow.

> In juices, water takes a tropical color

Enchanting melodies, echoing in the air,

> The sounds of raindrops are like melodies

Elevating the soul, relieving every care.

> Rain relieves from heat and drought

Softly brushing against the skin,
A feeling so tender, a connection to win.

> Falling rain brushes our skin

Comment: If your patience's running thin, maybe a hint is what you need. You may count down from 14, starting backwards from within. Once in Spanish's where you stop. Or better do it before, if a spoiler you want not. Who'd I even write this for? (Not a magic number: 7 * 2 = 14)